# Footer isn't responsive as responsive as it should be

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

The code is responsive for the most part but it creates that whitespace and the "Opening Hours" section doesn't go underneath the other section. I tried using a similar media query for another section of the code, but that doesn't do it much justice. I also looked at some other posts and read through them, but nothing really works either way. Please help!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html, body {
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
}

.page-wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
    background: #e1306c;
    color: white;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.footer .footer-content {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;

}

.footer-content1 {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 25px;
} 

.footer .footer-content h3 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 1500;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.footer .footer-content .about h3 span {
    color: #00bfff;
}

.footer .footer-content .about p {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.footer .footer-content .about .contact span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer .footer-content .about .socials a {
    border: 3px solid #00bfff;
    width: 45px;
    height: 41px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.footer .footer-content .about .socials a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #e1306c;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.footer .footer-content .hours ul a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.footer .footer-content .hours ul a:hover {
    color: #00bfff;
    margin-left: 15px;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.footer .footer-bottom {
    background: #00bfff;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .footer-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

   
}
```

```html
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer-content">

            <div class="footer-section about">
            <h3 class="logo-text"><span>Name </span>of Company</h3>
            <p>lorem zggz gsrggsrhrssrg rsrshsrh srhrs hsrhrs hrshsrhrshsr srhrdhrdsh srhsrhsrh rshrhdhrshsrh egeg</p>
            <div class="contact">
                <span><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> &nbsp; 000-000-0000</span>
                <span><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> &nbsp; company@gmail.com </span>
            </div>
            <div class="socials">
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
            <div class="footer-section hours">
                <h3>Opening Hours</h3>
                <br>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>MON - 8:00AM - 4:00PM</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>TUE - 8:00AM - 4:00PM</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>WED - 8:00AM - 4:00PM</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>THURS - 8:00AM - 4:00PM</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>FRI - 8:00AM - 4:00PM</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>SAT - CLOSED</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>SUN - CLOSED</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        

        <div class="footer-bottom">
            &copy; Name | Designed by Devz
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use min-height instead of height in .footer and .footer .footer-content

Your content overflows the container, when it changes to flex-direction: column, because it still has a set height.

```
.footer {
    background: #e1306c;
    color: white;
    min-height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.footer .footer-content {
    border: 1px solid;
    min-height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it ended up making it look all distorted, apparently it was an issue with my media query.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to add    `height:auto;`   in footer and footer-content  .

Please check the below solution in the snippet.

Let me know if anything else is required.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html, body {
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
}

.page-wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
    background: #e1306c;
    color: white;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.footer .footer-content {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;

}

.footer-content1 {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 25px;
} 

.footer .footer-content h3 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 1500;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.footer .footer-content .about h3 span {
    color: #00bfff;
}

.footer .footer-content .about p {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.footer .footer-content .about .contact span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer .footer-content .about .socials a {
    border: 3px solid #00bfff;
    width: 45px;
    height: 41px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.footer .footer-content .about .socials a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #e1306c;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.footer .footer-content .hours ul a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.footer .footer-content .hours ul a:hover {
    color: #00bfff;
    margin-left: 15px;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.footer .footer-bottom {
    background: #00bfff;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .footer{height:auto}
    .footer .footer-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      height:auto;
    }

   
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
        <div class="footer-content">

            <div class="footer-section about">
            <h3 class="logo-text"><span>Name </span>of Company</h3>
            <p>lorem zggz gsrggsrhrssrg rsrshsrh srhrs hsrhrs hrshsrhrshsr srhrdhrdsh srhsrhsrh rshrhdhrshsrh egeg</p>
            <div class="contact">
                <span><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> &nbsp; 000-000-0000</span>
                <span><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> &nbsp; company@gmail.com </span>
            </div>
            <div class="socials">
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
            <div class="footer-section hours">
                <h3>Opening Hours</h3>
                <br>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>MON - 8:00AM - 4:00PM</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>TUE - 8:00AM - 4:00PM</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>WED - 8:00AM - 4:00PM</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>THURS - 8:00AM - 4:00PM</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>FRI - 8:00AM - 4:00PM</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>SAT - CLOSED</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>SUN - CLOSED</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        

        <div class="footer-bottom">
            &copy; Name | Designed by Devz
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This solved my problem man! Its funny how with coding, missing one simple thing can mess it all up haha @AjayMalhotra

Answer (score -1):

To make your webpage/website responsive use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px`, `em` or `%`. (**Note:- *1vw=0.5cm***)

For Example, Use `height: 3.66vw;` instead of `height: 50px;`.

Try it, it will surely work but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Most of the responsive code is working. only the issue is height of footer and footer-content.

Comment: @AjayMalhotra Apply **Viewport Units** in footer only then footer will also be responsive.

Comment: @AjayMalhotra I have added an example in my answer, you ca do it in the similar way.

Comment: Can you add your code in code snippet. That will help us to know or learn new things. Your example is not enough to understand the solution. @shubh1834

Comment: @AjayMalhotra I would do that but currently I am busy on my own projects but you can get lot of resources to learn about **Viewport Units**online. Check them out you will really love using them. Sorry for not editing code.

Answer (score -1):

By removing the **absolute** `position` for `footer-bottom` I think you get what you were expecting.

```
.footer .footer-bottom {
    background: #00bfff;
//    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
//    bottom: 0px;
//    left: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The issue is with height of footer and footer-content class in css.